# Cannot enqueue large Oracle AQ message 

Tags: oracle11g, odp.net, oracle-aq

I am trying to `Enqueue` a message onto an Oracle Queue from a .NET client.  If the message exceeds a certain size, the following error occurs:

> ORA-01013: user requested cancel of current operation

This happens with both `XMLTYPE` and `raw` as the queue table's message type.

It seems that the size of the message is to blame but cannot tell for sure be cause of the limited Oracle error message.

Is there a limit on the size, can I increase the size or is there another way to overcome this issue?

**Update:**

- I am able to send the message directly with `dbms_aq.enqueue(...)`
- Setting the timeout from the .NET client does not have any effect. (It times out immediately regardless of the timeout value)

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a connection timeout from the .net client. Try increasing the timeout. If that doesn't work, check if the issue is with the message payload by inserting the message directly through dbms_aq.enqueue(...). If you are able insert, then the message itself is fine.

Comment: thanks for responding. I have updated my questions with the findings.

Comment: So the message size is not a problem. Can you include the definition of the queue payload type and may be the code snippet where you are trying to insert into the queue ?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of size-related issues being fixed for 11.2.0.3. See this non-authoritative list here:

http://www.eygle.com/Notes/11.2.0.3.html

Some examples:

```
9878459  Specific length object binds over 4k may be bound as NULL
10389881 Raw buffered message payload > 8k corrupted when dequeued 
         from a buffered queue
```

Maybe, your issue is in this list?